# My ganglia is not working on cluster so i want to monitor jobs using torque

Tags: cluster-computing, torque, ganglia

[ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) is not working on cluster so I want to monitor jobs using [torque](http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/products/open-source/torque/). Can I monitor all jobs through torque even which are not submitted through torque?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the qstat command, specifically 'qstat -f [job number]' which will give you additional information about your jobs. Of course, this will do nothing for jobs running outside of Torque. For those jobs you can look at the output of 'pbsnodes' and look at the data for each node but it would probably be easier to run those jobs through Torque as well.

If Maui or Moab are installed you can try 'checkjob -v [job number]' for job information and 'diagnose -n' or 'checknode [nodename]' for watching nodes.

Comment: Can, I use Maui or Moab as an alternative to Ganglia for monitoring all nodes at one time?

Comment: diagnose -n should give you load on Maui and Moab but won't give you the Ganglia style graphs. Moab may have more features but it is expensive.